# Can we create S3 buckets using AWS educate account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Can we create S3 buckets using AWS educate account?
If Yes, Where... I couldn't find any option in my AWS educate account.

I have tried to login with my educate account to usual AWS.. but couldn't. I know previously we could access S3 using educate. Have Amazon removed those services to Edcuate account?

Comment: Are you getting any error trying to create a S3 bucket?

Comment: What do you mean by "but couldn't"?

Comment: Here what I mean by couldn't is  when I try to login it says user doesn't exists.

Answer (score 1):

S3 is available with AWS Educate account, here is the list of the services

https://s3.amazonaws.com/awseducate-starter-account-services/AWS_Educate_Starter_Accounts_and_AWS_Services.pdf

can you try accessing the service directly

https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/home?region=us-east-1#

Comment: S3 is global (on the console). You do not need to change the region in order to access S3.

Comment: Is it still working?